# Sorting 2D array String with number fields

Tags: java, string, sorting, multidimensional-array, integer

I think many people have come across this problem,
You have a 2D array consisting of a String conponent and an Interger.
ex.

```
    `String[][] data = {{"Name1","5"}, {"Name2","10"},{"Name3","1"}, {"Name4","3"}};`
```

Now you want to sort that 2D array by the integer (in this case the players score), however you want the matching name to be moved along with the players score.
This is what i've got, but the result is far away from what it is suppose to be.

```
    private void sort(){
    boolean sort;
    int current, next;
    do{
            sort = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++){
                if (data[i][1] !=null && data[i+1][1] != null){
                    current = Integer.parseInt(data[i][1]);
                    next = Integer.parseInt(data[i+1][1]);
                        if(current > next){
                                String temp = "";
                                data[i][1] = Integer.toString(next); 
                                data[i+1][1] = Integer.toString(current);
                                data[i][0] = temp;
                                data[i][0] = data[i+1][1];
                                data[i+1][0] = temp;       
                                sort = false;
                        }
                }

            }

    }while(!sort);
}
```

If you ask why people would use a common 2D array, it is because in JFRAME, a JTable needs an 2D array for the data.

Comment: See my answer: while not generic enough, it can give hindsights. In essence, your array elements need to be able to compare to one another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a special Comparator, wich can compare e.g.
`{"Name1","5"}` and `{"Name2","10"}`
But I recomment to change your data structure.

I would create a type caonatining *name* and *int*

```
class NameNum{
   String name;
   int number;
}
```

and store them in a 1D Array

```
NameNum[] data
```

Implement a compare method and than simply use `Arrays.sort(..)` to sort the array.

Comment: While your are at it, why not make the `NameNum` class implement `Comparable` of itself? It would allow to use some very convenient collections primitives ;)

Comment: Well, implementing `Comparable` in this case looks like a good idea since you can use `SortedSet` to full effect, see my answer.

Comment: Instead of creating a new class you could also maintain a `Map` that maps the `"nameN"` strings to ints (or int strings w/e) and work with that. That seems more fitting in my opinion.

Comment: @A.R.S. that would be a solution, but it does not account for the fact that two players with a different name can have the same score

Comment: A `Map` or a `Set` can only be used, if every Key / Entry will be unique, what we do not know from rge description given in the question.

Comment: @MrSmith42 wrong: see edit -- as we are guaranteed that a tuple (player, score) is unique, we can limit ourselves to implementing `Comparable`. A `SortedSet` _does not_ check for element equality, it only requires that its elements implement `Comparable`.

Comment: @fge Sure it does - we're mapping the *names* to the *scores*, hence the *scores* do not need to be unique.

Comment: @MrSmith42 That's true I suppose, although I was assuming that the names would be unique (although you're right, we're not certain).

Comment: @A.R.S. so what? If you use a map pairing score to names, it means that the names can be multiple for a same score. I don't understand your point?

Comment: @fge: I wanted to point out you cannot put two elements `o1`, `o2` in a `Set` such that `o1.compare(o2)==0`. For the `Map` idea of 
*@A.R.S* there can not be equal keys.

Comment: @MrSmith42: well, if you look at my implementation, you can see that this can basically never happen in this case, unless the upper programming layer allows for it ;) Bah...

Comment: @fge I'm saying we can use a `Map<String, Integer>` (assuming the names in his original array are unique). Just another possible implementation, in addition to creating a new class.

Comment: @A.R.S. the problem is that it must be the _scores_ which come first

Comment: @fge With the `Map<String,Integer>`, we can sort the map's entry set based on values (with a custom comparator).

Comment: @A.R.S. sure we can but why bother when we can build a `SortedSet` with easily instantiable objects as my answer demonstrates? (and which does the right thing wrt comparison from the start since it implements `Comparable` of itself)

Comment: @fge Well I guess we'll leave the choice to the OP; I was just presenting an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: your array elements do *not* consist of a string and an integer since in:

```
{ "Name1", "5" }
```

`"5"` is not an `Integer` but a `String`.

Provided that you do not care about equality, the solution here is to create a wrapper object over this tuple, make it implement `Comparable` of itself and use a `SortedSet`. You will have to reverse it for display, and fortunately the JDK also has builtin methods for that.

Sample code:

```
private static final String[][] data = {
    { "Name1", "5" },
    { "Name2", "10" },
    { "Name3", "1" },
    { "Name4", "3" }
};

private static final class Score
    implements Comparable<Score>
{
    private final String name;
    private final int score;

    private Score(final String name, final String scoreAsString)
    {
        this.name = name;
        // NOTE: this can throw an (unchecked) NumberFormatException,
        // but this code assumes that it never does
        score = Integer.parseInt(scoreAsString);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final Score o)
    {
        final int ret = score - o.score;
        return ret != 0 ? ret : name.compareTo(o.name);
    }

    // Print results nicely ;)
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Name: " + name + ", score: " + score;
    }
}

public static void main(final String... args)
{
    final SortedSet<Score> set = new TreeSet<Score>();
    Score score;

    for (final String[] raw: data) {
        score = new Score(raw[0], raw[1]);
        set.add(score);
    }

    // Build a List from that Set...
    final List<Score> scoreList = new ArrayList<Score>(set);

    // Reverse it...
    Collections.reverse(scoreList);

    // Print results
    for (final Score s: scoreList)
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

Copy/paste the above code in a class, run it: you will see that it does what is intended.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: yes, this custom class does *not* override `equals()`/`hashCode()`; this is not an oversight: as only comparison is required here (since a `SortedSet` is used), there was no reason for implementing them at all.

Comment: since a player could play the game multiple times, he won't be unique.

Comment: Well, the code will work equally well in that event, the comparison will just return 0 ;) Edited...